# Ditto (clipboard manager): can't set shortcut of Win+<num>. Get “Error Registering Position 1”

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard, productivity, ditto

Someone made a YouTube video on Ditto (maybe [this one?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spS0wW_6iZc)), and that person uses <kbd>Win</kbd>+*Num* to paste items from the list. He put a screenshot of his settings on Google Plus:

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts tab of Ditto options window]

When I try to do the same, which is to put “1” in the text field of Position 1, and check the “Win” box to add the Windows key as the sole modifier for the shortcut, which will be <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, I get an error that says “Error Registering Position 1” in a window titled CP_Main:

[image: Error window]

Could it be because <kbd>Win</kbd>+*Num* conflicts
with the natural <kbd>Win</kbd>+*Num* shortcut (starts the application pinned to the taskbar in that position, or switches to that program) of Windows 7?

Comment: The bindings defined in Windows can be overridden without problems. Try loading the default layout (en_US) and running that application. I'm suspecting that the modifier keys are defined differently for your current layout.

Comment: I went to "Text Services and Input Languages" and my "Default input language" is already English (United States). Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on Windows 7. After editing the registry according to http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm I could reasign the first hotkey to Win + F1, though. Looks like Win + F1 was already occupied by Windows.

Comment: Is there a way around this without having to disable EVERY native Windows hotkey? I like most of them. Would like to assign to Win+F1 though. Although technically I guess that would be the equivalent of normal paste anyway, if assigned to position 1. But it seems I can no longer use Win + V as of Windows 8 or 8.1 which is a bit disappointing. That's the hotkey I've always used for Ditto. :\

Comment: This didn't work for me...

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to disable *all* windows shortcut. Install Autohotkey (which is a good idea anyways) and enable the following script.

In the case you want it on `WIN` + `V`

```
#v::
  Run C:\Program Files\Ditto\Ditto.exe /Open
Return
```

Use `#^v::` if you want it on `WIN` + `Shift` + `V`

Comment: If you are a power user wanting to use a clipboard manager, then you are also a good candidate to start using Autohotkey.  I'm already using AHK so this solution was a quick copy/paste into my general .ahk script file.